# Magento - get item stock/quantity per site

Tags: magento

How to get actual stock number per site/store id.
So I have 2 stores, UK (1) and US (2) currently I am using:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(1);
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ID);
$product->setStoreId(1);
$qty = $product->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

The issue is that `$qty` returned is a sum of both rather than just UK (1).

Any ideas how to get quantity only for specific store and not a sum of both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inventory managed globally in magento and it cannot be changed on store view or website level in magento.

thanks

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what do you mean, particularly by 'we'?

Comment: Magento dont have an option to manage stocks on website/store level. It has to be one value shared among stores.

Comment: Thanks, I found it how its being used, some extension.

Comment: @Marcin Did you find any solution to get the exact value of the intventory for that store?